# How do you use PI in Excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write an equation in Excel but I keep getting `#NAME?` in the cell.

I think it is related to the use of `PI` but am not sure since the rest is just numbers or cell references.

This is what I wrote in my formula:

```
= ( 4 * (pi) * A2^2 * 5.671*10^(-8) * (B2)^4 )
```

[image: screenshot of sheet]

I applied it to each row and every row gives the same `#NAME?` output. It's not clear what i am getting wrong. Hope someone can help explain what I am doing wrong.

One thing I notice is it keeps making PI lowercase, why though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PI](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pi-function-264199d0-a3ba-46b8-975a-c4a04608989b) is a function and not a variable or cell name so it must be called with `()`

```
=4 * PI() * A2^2 * 5.671*10^(-8) * (B2)^4
```

Comment: Oh i see, damn was so simple after all. Thanks !